# Custom keyboard built into app UI

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-events

I've built the buttons into a layout file and I have a switch statement to address all of them. Most of them work fine I'm using

```
code.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)); //code is the EditText name
```

This works fine for all the characters there is a key for. But I need to add >, < and ? keys which don't work consistently. I've tried making it send KeyEvents for alt then doing x and z for > < but that doesn't work in the virtual device because that has a different keyboard layout than my Droid. I couldn't get the ? to work on either I tried shift then / for the virtual device but it doesn't work and on my droid it has it's own key.

How can I send the characters that don't have their own keys?

Answer (score 0):

```
code.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), ">", 0, KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD));
```

Well I noticed this KeyEvent Method. Although I'm not sure what it wants where I put 0, in the documentation it says "The device ID that generated the key event." So, what goes here?